# Total electric field between two non-parallel plates

Tags: electric-fields, electrons, acceleration, velocity

We know that electric field $E$ is given by voltage $V$ divided by distance between electrodes $d$, *i.e.* $E=V/d$.

My question is how strong will an electric field be if the distance between the plates is different at the two ends?  In other words, the plates are not parallel?

How would an electron act if it entered an electric field made by non-parallel electrodes?  How would its acceleration and velocity be affected?

Comment: Welcome to [Physics.SE]!  I will edit your question for clarity, and to make it clear that you're not asking how to solve a particular problem.  Please feel free to roll back these changes and/or edit the question further if I make changes that conflict with your intent.

Comment: You will have to solve a partial differential equation to find the potential,  and from that the field.

Comment: If area of cross section is uniform for both the plates then potential difference will also be same. Am I right ?